# Amazon ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer: when changing permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, permissions, ssh-keys

I went on to my amazon ec2 successfully and I have been experimenting around. I found it annoying that I needed to always run sudo on everything so what I decided to do was to go to the route directory and change the permissions of everything to write, write, and execute.

I did so doing the following

```
chmod -R 777 .
```

I then exited out of the server.

The next time I tried to logon I got

```
"ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer"
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 33):

My solution is probably trivial, but who knows who it could help:

I simply rebooted my EC2 instance in the browser (AWS -> EC2 Dashboard -> instances -> (select your instance) -> (click the action dropdown) -> Instance State -> Reboot

You may want to give it a minute before you try you ssh connection command again. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: reboot did not help me, I needed to stop the instances and start again to solved the problem. But major problem is that I need to do this every day.

Is there any permanent solution?

Comment: Rebooting the instance worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Heavy Server Load

Have also seen this happen when server was under heavy load from for example, brute force attack. Increase the amount of connections sshd can run.
http://edoceo.com/notabene/ssh-exchange-identification

Answer (score 8):

In my case instance stop and start worked.

I simply rebooted my EC2 instance in the browser (AWS -> EC2 Dashboard -> instances -> (select your instance) -> (click the action dropdown) -> Instance State -> Stop

then

I simply rebooted my EC2 instance in the browser (AWS -> EC2 Dashboard -> instances -> (select your instance) -> (click the action dropdown) -> Instance State -> Start

Note:- It takes a while for stop and start, have some patience.

thanks
Pranav

Comment: Don't use this if your instance is live. This approach will change IPs and you're in for more shock! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55414302/an-ip-address-of-ec2-instance-gets-changed-after-the-restart

Answer (score 4):

As a helpful annotation, I had this case in a shared hosting environment, specifically GoDaddy, and the reason It gave me this error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Solution: my local machine's ip had been blocked by GoDaddy, so I had to contact their support, send them a screenshot of the error output from running:

> ssh -v user@domain

, and also provide them with my ip. They noticed my ip had been in fact blocked, removed it, and problem solved.

Additionally, you should not have your keys be in a 777 chmod. You should change them to 700.

Comment: I know you're right but right now I called them and they say: "we don't block IP addresses!!!"

Comment: Yeah, they are little angels :3

Comment: just a note - keys should be 400

Answer (score -1):

The reason ssh 22 has disable for EC2 from Security group or IP of system where you are connecting EC2 over ssh port 22. Go to EC2-->Security group and Inbound Port and add ssh port.