# getting error message "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer" in AWS

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I installed word press in an AWS ec2 instance.

Configuration is as follows:

```
1.Installed  on amazon-ux,
2.other application installed were -  php, php-mysql, rds, httpd, word press. 
3.Installation was succesful , I managed to connect to the RDS MYSQL db too. 

4.Manged to upload pics and was able to replicate it from the cloud front too 
5.But the instance gets hung every few hours [say ..may be every 6- 7 hrs] this is my third ec2 instance  and i am facing the same issue all the time . When i try to SSH in to my instance , i get this error message "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer in AWS" .
```

I have to reboot it every time to fix the issue .

Comment: Have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463684/amazon-ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer-when-changin

Comment: wow, that makes sense !! thanks manish !! i am testing it . i changed the permission for my .pem file. Will keep this thread updated with the outcome.